# Tableau - Unable to execute BigQuery view which is created using standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

I'm unable to execute a BigQuery view which created using Standard SQL. Below is the error:

> The Google BigQuery service was unable to compile the query. 
>       Cannot reference a SQL view in a Legacy SQL query.

```
Tableau version - 9.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#logical_views), you cannot query a logical view defined with legacy SQL using standard SQL and vice versa due to differences in syntax and semantics between the dialects. In order to query the view, you will need to use standard SQL.

See also the [Tableau help page](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_googlebigquery.html#switch_to_bql) about switching between the dialects.

Comment: I'm using Tableau version - 9.3 which accepts Legacy SQL views and fail to run views created using Standard SQL. What should I do to make Tableau to run Standard SQL view?

Comment: It looks like [Tableau version 10.1](http://www.tableau.com/support/releases/10.1.0) was the first to enable standard SQL by default and provide the ability to change between the dialects, so you may need to update before you can query the view defined using standard SQL.